# Relations between an affine space and a topological space

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, geometry, affine-geometry

What is the relation between an [affine space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space) and a [topological space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space)? Is one a specialization of the other?

Moreover, what do we call a point in geometry: an element of a topological space or an element of an affine space ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You may have different topologies on the same affine space and you can have topological spaces without any affine structure.

Comment: See the edited question.